# AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'member' - Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm trying to make it so that a moderator could register a user onto a JSON file, where we store currency.

This is my code, I'm getting the error :

```py
id = str(ctx.message.member.id)
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'member'
```

````py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def registeruser(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    id = str(ctx.message.member.id)
    if id not in amounts:
        amounts[id] = 0
        await ctx.send("You are now registered to AccoladeBot.")
        _save()
    else:
        await ctx.send("You already have an account.")```
````

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the specified user has an account or not, you should write `str(member.id)` instead of `str(ctx.message.member.id)`

```
@bot.command()
async def registeruser(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    id = str(member.id)
    if id not in amounts:
        amounts[id] = 0
        await ctx.send("You are now registered to AccoladeBot.")
        _save()
    else:
        await ctx.send("You already have an account.")
```

More about the `Context` object [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context).

Comment: Gives me a second error: NameError: name 'message' is not defined

Comment: It should come from another part of your code, there's no "message" variable in the command I gave :/